# DISTINCT not working in SELECT PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query works without the "distinct" keyword, but it returns duplicated films

```
SELECT DISTINCT film.name from film
INNER JOIN participation on film.cod_film=participation.cod_film
    where year<2000 AND professional.name='Kenneth Branagh'
    ORDER BY year ASC;
```

with the "distinct", I get this error:

```
db error: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

Comment: What have you found unclear in the message "for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list"

Comment: It says that I should select "year", but it does not make sense for me. First, I want to order by year, then select only unique films names

Comment: I don't want "year" to be in the resulting query

Comment: What if there are two different `film.name`s with different `year`? If they are grouped into a single result row, how should they be sorted? Can you see now that your query doesn't make sense?

Comment: Due to the fact your query doesn't make sense, it would be better to show sample data and expected outcome, then people can think about another query which does better.

Comment: The issue is order of operations. A `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` is ran before an `ORDER BY`. Therefore you can't `ORDER BY` a column that isn't existing after the `DISTINCT` has acted. Perhaps instead you might consider  `SELECT name FROM (SELECT film.name, max(year) as filmyear FROM <existing from statement> GROUP BY film.name)  AS dt ORDER BY filmyear`.

Comment: Suppose the movie Hair was made in 1969 and 2023. Is it supposed to appear twice in your list or once? Or, if there are two movies named Hair in 1969, and one movie named Hair ini 2023, once or twice? Since you are not outputting the year, why do you care?